# When I click submit button the data in invoice is inserted but the particulars is not inserting

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-8

These are my codes in controller. Do you think the validation is not correct or the foreach? I have tried to fix this but still can't do it.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {  
    $invoice = $request->validate($this->validation());

    //This invoice create is working
    $value = Invoice::create([
        'customer_name' => $invoice['customer_name'],
        'currency' => $invoice['currency'],
        'invoice_date' => $invoice['invoice_date'],
        'due_date' => $invoice['due_date'],
        'invoice_no' => $invoice['invoice_no'],
        'po_ref_no' => $invoice['po_ref_no'],
        'notes' => $invoice['notes'],
        'recurring' => $invoice['recurring'],    
    ]);
    
    //This is not working
    foreach ($invoice['particulars'] as $record) {
        $value->particulars()->create($record);
    }

    return $this->respondWithMessage('invoice successfully saved.');
 }
```

// This is my validation

```
private function validation()
{
    return [
        //INVOICES TABLE
        'customer_name' => ['nullable'],
        'currency' => ['nullable'],
        'invoice_date' => ['nullable'],
        'due_date' => ['nullable'],
        'invoice_no' => ['nullable'],
        'po_ref_no' => ['nullable'],
        'notes' => ['nullable'],
        'recurring' => ['nullable'],

        //PARTICULARS TABLE
        'particulars' => ['array'],
        'particulars.*.ref_no' => ['nullable'],
        'particulars.*.description' => ['nullable'],
        'particulars.*.unit' => ['nullable'],
        'particulars.*.quantity' => ['nullable'],
        'particulars.*.unit_price' => ['nullable'],
        'particulars.*.vat' => ['nullable'],
        'particulars.*.total' => ['nullable'],
        
    ];
}
```

Comment: any validation errors? what's the output of dd($request->get('particulars'))?

Comment: Like @JoshuaAngnoe said, try to dd($invoice['particulars']) and check what you get.